# Mathematica's "POV" export format ignores ColorFunction

Tags: export, graphics3d, color

I was playing with [xslittlegrass's Pov-Ray package](http://xslittlegrass.wordpress.com/) and more generally with the POV-conversion function `ExportString[#, "POV"] &`, and noticed that `ExportString[#, "POV"] &` seems to ignore colors given to objects using `ColorFunction`.

For example:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ], Sin[ϕ] Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {θ, 0, π},
 PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, ϕ, θ}, Hue[Sin[6 ϕ] Sin[6 θ]]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

However, applying `ExportString[#, "POV"] &` to the previous graphics object yields a POV-Ray script which, when rendered, consists entirely of white triangles:

[image]

So it seems that the surface coloration provided by the `ColorFunction` specified in the plot does not get converted to the POV output at all.

Is there some way to correctly export the plot colors provided by `ColorFunction`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like you, I found no colours in the output *.pov file. Mathematica recognises
the pov extension, but `Export["povtest.pov",pplot3D]` outputs all triangle objects with white colour: `pigment {color rgb <1, 1, 1>}`.

I took the brute-force approach and decomposed the 3D plot into vertices,
triangles, and colours.

Define the 3D plot.

```
pplot3D = ParametricPlot3D[
     {Cos[p] Sin[t], Sin[p] Sin[t], Cos[t]},
     {p, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {t, 0, \[Pi]},
     PlotPoints->150, Mesh->None,
     ColorFunction->Function[{x, y, z, p, t}, Hue[Sin[6 p] Sin[6 t]]],
     ColorFunctionScaling->False];
```

Find the vertices, triangles, and vertex colours.

```
vertices = pplot3D[[1, 1]];
triangles = pplot3D[[1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]];
colours = Chop[Map[ColorConvert[#, "RGB"]&, pplot3D[[1, 3, 2]]]];
```

Define an auxillary function forming a string from triples of real numbers,
avoiding exponents. The order of the three components {x,y,z} is switched
to match the POVRay convention of {x,z,y}.

```
AccString[x_List] := 
   StringDrop[ StringJoin[
      Map[ToString[AccountingForm[#, NumberSigns->{"-", ""}]]<>","&,
          x[[{1,3,2}]]]], -1]
```

Define a function to write POVRay triangle objects.

```
POVtriangle[ind_List] :=
   StringJoin[{
      "triangle{<",
         AccString[vertices[[ind[[1]]]]], ">,<", 
         AccString[vertices[[ind[[2]]]]], ">,<", 
         AccString[vertices[[ind[[3]]]]], "> pigment{colour rgb <", 
         AccString[Mean[Apply[List, colours[[ind]], 1]]], ">}}"}]
```

Export the triangles to a POVRay include file.

```
Export["povtest.inc", Map[POVtriangle, triangles], "Lines"]
```

Create the file povtest.pov file with the camera and lights, and include povtest.inc.

```
camera { location <0, 10, -50>  angle 3
     up y*image_height right x*image_width look_at <0, 0, 0> }
light_source { <0, 20,  -500> colour rgb 2 * <1,1,1> shadowless }
light_source { <0, 20,  500> colour rgb 2 * <1,1,1> shadowless }
#include "povtest.inc"
```

The vertex normals are found in `pplot3D[[1,4,2]]`, and may be used to form POVRay smooth triangles. Other options are found in `pplot3D[[2]]`.
[image: sphereplot]

Answer (score 6):

## Convert GraphicsComplex to mesh2

To preserve the color and smoothness of the 3D plot, we can take the GraphicsComplex object in Mathematica and then turn it into a mesh2 object in POVRay. Since these two objects have very similar structure, the conversion is pretty straight forward.

The advantage of using mesh2 object is that it will interpolate the data (and color) from the vertex and its norm vector and produce a smooth colored surface.

A 3D graphics in Mathematica is usually constructed from a [`GraphicsComplex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsComplex.html) object. And the  `GraphicsComplex` object has a structure like:

```
GraphicsComplex[vertex,polygons,VertexColors->vertexColors,VertexNormals->vertexNormals]
```

This structure is actually very similar to the mesh2 object in POVRay. A typical mesh2 object in POVRay has the following structure:

```
mesh2{
        vertex_vectors{
            ...
        }
        normal_vectors{
            ...
        }
        face_indices{
            ...
        }
    }
```

The conversion from the GraphicsComplex to mesh2 can be done easily with some string manipulations.

## Some examples

Here are some examples of POVRay rendered 3D graphics with color

```
p1 = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[p] Sin[t], Sin[p] Sin[t], Cos[t]}, {p, 0, 
    2 π}, {t, 0, π}, PlotPoints -> 150, Mesh -> None, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, p, t}, Hue[Sin[6 p] Sin[6 t]]],
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ImageSize -> 300];
p2 = SphericalPlot3D[
   Evaluate@Abs@SphericalHarmonicY[5, 2, θ, ϕ], {θ,0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, Mesh -> None, 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r}, 
     Evaluate[
      Hue@Rescale[Arg@SphericalHarmonicY[5, 2, θ, ϕ], {-π, π}]]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 50, 
   ImageSize -> 300];
p3 = SphericalPlot3D[1 + Sin[5 ϕ] Sin[10 θ]/10, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, 
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["GreenPinkTones"][#6] &), Mesh -> None,
    PlotPoints -> 50, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
   ImageSize -> 300];
```

export and render in POVRay

```
Transpose[{#, Show[POVRayRender[#, ImageSize -> {400, 300}], 
          ImageSize -> 300]} & /@ {p1, p2, p3}] // Grid
```

[image]

## The package

The `POVRayRender` function comes from the `POVRayRender` package that can be downloaded from the [github repo](https://github.com/xslittlegrass/POVRayRender-For-Mathematica).

Comment: The code you link to throws an Error: First::nofirst: {} has zero length and no first element. Function::slotn: Slot number 1 in <<>ToString[#1]<>,<>ToString[#2]<>,<>ToString[#3]<>>& cannot be filled from (<<>ToString[#1]<>,<>ToString[#2]<>,<>ToString[#3]<>>&)[]. Function::slotn: Slot number 2 in <<>ToString[#1]<>,<>ToString[#2]<>,<>ToString[#3]<>>& cannot be filled from (<<>ToString[#1]<>,<>ToString[#2]<>,<>ToString[#3]<>>&)[]. Function::slotn: Slot number 3 in <<>ToString[#1]<>,<>ToString[#2]<>,<>ToString[#3]<>>& cannot be filled from (<<>ToString[#1]<>,<>ToString[#2]<>,<>ToString[#3]<>>&)[]

Comment: @furry, you did not mention what your input was that led to these errors, so it's a little difficult to diagnose. Why not give the code for whatever it was you were trying to render?

Comment: @J.M. I tried: `Get["PovrayRender.m"]; p3 = SphericalPlot3D[1 + Sin[5 ϕ] Sin[10 θ]/10, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, ColorFunction -> (ColorData["GreenPinkTones"][#6] &), Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 300]; POVRayRender[p3]` I think the problem is in this line: `faceIndex = First@Cases[gc, GraphicsGroup[{Polygon[x__], ___}] :> x, ∞] - 1;` of the graphicsComplex to mesh2 function. When I run that, replacing gc, I get: `First::nofirst: {} has zero length and no first element.`

Comment: @furryplatypus It seems to be caused by a bug introduced in version 11.01. I have fixed the code in the github repo.